# syncing the test and live ExpressionEngine database

Tags: database, synchronization, expressionengine

We just started using EE and are very happy with it, but we are running into a problem.
We got a development/test server and a live server.
The problem is when the site is live and we want to make changes, for example add a plugin.
We add the plugin to the development/test server but then we got 2 different databases,
if we want to push our changes to the live server we can’t replace the live database because then the data inserted by our customer will be overwritten.
And syncing the database is a tricky job for which we need to examine the database really good.
Because of the possibility of the same id’s in the 2 databases referring to 2 different things.

I am curious if other have the same problem and if someone found a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you would create a module  instead of a plugin (or combine the two) if you need to create and manage your database tables. This allows you to create installation, uninstallation and update procedures.

By doing so, you will enable yourself to push a module (with plugins, extension and what not) to the production server and install the module correctly, without disturbing the existing data.

Answer (score 0):

This is the age-old question of database-driven sites and production/staging/dev servers. There is no answer other than to migrate database changes manually, or write custom scripts to do it for you.